# Pointer or Value in my case?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
bool example1()
{
    long a;
    a = 0;
    cout << a;
    a = 1;
    cout << a;
    a = 2;
    cout << a;
    //and again...again until
    a = 1000000;
    cout << a+1;
    return true;
}
bool example2()
{
    long* a = new long;//sorry for the misstake
    *a = 0;
    cout << *a;
    *a = 1;
    cout << *a;
    *a = 2;
    cout << *a;
    //and again...again until
    *a = 1000000;
    cout << *a + 1;
    return true;
}
```

Note that I do not delete *a* in example2(), just a newbie's questions:
1. When the two functions are executing, which one use more memories?
2. After the function return, which one make the whole program use more memories?
Thanks for your help!

UPATE: just repace **long* a;** with **long* a = new long;**
UPDATE 2: to avoid the case that we are not doing anything with *a*, I cout the value each time.

Comment: The first program is going to use more memory, because the second program is going to crash as soon as you make the first dereference of the uninitialized pointer :)

Comment: The second one is going to have something really bad happen. Your pointer's not initialized...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization See: When to optimize

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It's undefined behavior. Maybe it will crash, maybe not.

Comment: You might want to take a look at loops : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop

Comment: Sorry, my bad, just fixed the code!

Comment: @nvcnvn You 2nd program wins! Memory leak says hi!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Original answer

It depends and there will be no difference, at the same time.

The first program is going to consume `sizeof(long)` bytes on the stack, and the second is going to consume `sizeof(long*)`. Typically `long*` will be *at least as big* as a `long`, so you could say that the second program might use more memory (depends on the compiler and architecture).

On the other hand, stack memory is allocated with OS memory page granularity (4KB would be a good estimate), so both programs are almost guaranteed to use the same number of memory pages for the stack. In this sense, from the viewpoint of someone observing the system, memory usage is going to be identical.

But it gets better: the compiler is free to decide (depending on settings) that you are not really doing anything with these local variables, so it might decide to simply not allocate any memory at all in both cases.

And finally you have to answer the "what does the pointer point to" question (as others have said, the way the program is currently written it will almost surely crash due to accessing invalid memory when it runs).

Assuming that it does not (let's say the pointer is initialized to a valid memory address), would you count that memory as being "used"?

### Update (`long* a = new long` edit):

Now we know that the pointer will be valid, and heap memory will be allocated for a `long` (but not released!). Stack allocation is the same as before, but now `example2` will also use at least `sizeof(long)` bytes on the heap as well (in all likelihood it will use even more, but you can't tell how much because that depends on the heap allocator in use, which in turn depends on compiler settings etc).

Now from the viewpoint of someone observing the system, it is still unlikely that the two programs will exhibit different memory footprints (because the heap allocator will most likely satisfy the request for the `new long` in `example2` from memory in a page that it has already received from the OS), but there will certainly be less free memory available in the address space of the process. So in this sense, `example2` would use more memory. How much more? Depends on the overhead of the allocation which is unknown as discussed previously.

Finally, since `example2` does not release the heap memory before it exits (i.e. there is a memory leak), it will continue using heap memory even after it returns while `example1` will not.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one way to know, which is by measuring. Since you never actually use any of the values you assign, a compiler could, under the "as-if rule" simply optimize both functions down to:

```
bool example1()
{
    return true;
}
bool example2()
{
    return true;
}
```

That would a perfectly valid interpretation of your code under the rules of C++. It's up to you to compile and measure it to see what actually happens.

---

Sigh, an edit to the question made a difference to the above. The main point still stands: you can't know unless you measure it. Now both of the functions can be optimized to:

```
bool example1()
{
    cout << 0;
    cout << 1;
    cout << 2;
    //and again...again until
    cout << 1000001;
    return true;
}
bool example2()
{
    cout << 0;
    cout << 1;
    cout << 2;
    //and again...again until
    cout << 1000001;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @nvcnvn The relevant parts of my answer still stand: **measure** it. Anything else is just guessing.

Comment: @nvcnvn I made an edit. You may want to read: https://punchlet.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/letter-the-eighth-bedevilling-benchmarks/

Answer (score 0):

`example2()` never allocates memory for the value referenced by pointer `a`. If it did, it would take slightly more memory because it would require the space required for a `long` as well as space for the pointer to it.

Also, no matter how many times you assign a value to `a`, no more memory is used.

Answer (score 0):

example 2 has a problem of not allocating memory for the pointer. Pointer a initially has an unknown value which makes it to point to **somewhere** in memory. assigning values to this pointer corrupts the content of that **somewhere**.

both examples use same amount of memory. (which is 4 bytes.)